# Docker + Django Не сохраняется sqlite3 база данных

Tags: django, nginx, docker

У меня django проект развернут при помощи docker. Я запускаю проект при помощи `docker-compose up --build`, делаю какие-либо изменения, потом выключаю сайт, и заново запускаю этой командой, но никакие данные в бд не сохранились. Использую sqlite3 по умолчанию.

Файл docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: ./core
    expose:
      - 8000
  nginx:
    build: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro

volumes:
  media-data:
```

Структура проекта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]